# Efficient replacement of rows or columns of 2d arrays

Tags: python

I need a lot of operations to replace parts of the array repeatedly, I hope there is an efficient way to avoid loops, because I found that 2d array slicing does not support write operations.So I constructed a simple function to achieve this goal.

```
a = np.random.rand(4,4)
b = np.random.rand(4)
c = [1,1,1,1]

def ravel_index(a,b,row_index,col_index,order='c'):
    rindex = row_index * a.shape[1] + col_index
    lindex = rindex + b.ravel().shape[0]
    return rindex,lindex

f,l = ravel_index(a,b,1,0)
a.ravel()[f:l]=c

print (a) 

>>>[[ 0.013631517  0.81654666   0.96975073   0.832641632]
   [ 1.           1.           1.           1.         ]
   [ 0.092047737  0.149801674  0.322049501  0.162026284]
   [ 0.490197753  0.54935894   0.527087062  0.126544099]]
```

It looks ideal now, But when trying to write in column direction..

```
f,l = ravel_index(a,b,1,0)
a.ravel('F')[f:l]=c

print (a) 

>>>[[ 0.306372691  0.586445896  0.052487946  0.864993735]
    [ 0.873470159  0.762572666  0.986864265  0.803903923]
    [ 0.000208709  0.579103322  0.811386673  0.196167481]
    [ 0.928682626  0.707539068  0.752064295  0.564061717]]
```

Obviously the array is copied, I don't know how to solve this problem, hope to get help Thank you

Comment: `a[:,1] = c` _"2d array slicing does not support write operations"_??

Comment: I made a mistake because it was easy to find an array test, but I didn't notice that the array was not a basic array, but a slice. The result was incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for `numpy.ravel` mentions that

> A copy is made only if needed

which means that `ravel('F')` won't be the solution you're looking for. If you assume instead that everything is in order `'C'`, you can modify your `ravel_index` function:

```
def ravel_index(a,c,row_index,col_index,order='c'):

    rindex = row_index * a.shape[1] + col_index
    if order == 'c':
        lindex = rindex + b.ravel().shape[0]
        return range(rindex, lindex)
    elif order == 'f':
        lindex = rindex + a.shape[1]*np.ravel(c).shape[0]
        return (None, range(rindex, lindex, a.shape[1]))
```

E.g.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(4,4)
>>> c = [1,1,1,1]
>>> ravel_slice = ravel_index(a,c,0,1,order='f')
>>> a.ravel()[ravel_slice]=c
>>>
>>> print a
[[0.56152208 1.         0.76850125 0.90981706]
 [0.00753469 1.         0.33609404 0.01321701]
 [0.36101786 1.         0.36610868 0.77170151]
 [0.64812018 1.         0.33486985 0.58649772]]
```